# Vuejs - require is not defined

Tags: vue.js

I am just playing around with vuejs router and try to load a component.
I used the sample code and changed `foo`

```
// Define some components
var Foo = Vue.extend({
    template: require('./components/test.vue')
});

var Bar = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>This is bar!</p>'
});

// The router needs a root component to render.
// For demo purposes, we will just use an empty one
// because we are using the HTML as the app template.
var App = Vue.extend({})

// Create a router instance.
// You can pass in additional options here, but let's
// keep it simple for now.
var router = new VueRouter()

// Define some routes.
// Each route should map to a component. The "component" can
// either be an actual component constructor created via
// Vue.extend(), or just a component options object.
// We'll talk about nested routes later.
router.map({
    '/foo': {
        component: Foo
    },
    '/bar': {
        component: Bar
    }
})

// Now we can start the app!
// The router will create an instance of App and mount to
// the element matching the selector #app.
router.start(App, '#app')
```

I also tested it with

```
Vue.component('Foo', {
    template: require('./components/test.vue')
})
```

In my `test.vue` i have

```
<template>

<h2>Test</h2>

</template>
```

But not as soon as i use `require` i get everytime the error `Required is not defined` in my dev tools.

What do i wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is a builtin in the NodeJS environment and used in Grunt build environments.

If you also want to use it in a browser environment you can integrate this version of it: http://requirejs.org

Comment: Yeah - thanks for your answer. I already figured it out because `required` and now i am using http://browserify.org/

Comment: Node.js's `require` comes from its CommonJS module support. RequireJS is a library for AMD modules. They are **not compatible**. They both provide a function named `require` but it takes different arguments and expects modules to be designed differently.

Answer (score 1):

**(Author) This is outdated:**

Use `Browserify` or `Webpack` as there is active support in the Vue community

http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Deploying_for_Production (dead link)

I personally used [this repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-browserify-example) of the Vue GitHub-org to get started quickly.

> **Edit:**
> This has moved on a bit in early 2018.
>
> Deployment guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html
>
> 'getting started' type repo: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader

Comment: All the links are dead

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Adding the outdated label.